# Lazy loaded module in named outlet throws error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

When I try to load a module using loadChildren to load a module's component in named outlet, its throwing error.

Is there a way to lazy load module in a named router-outlet?

```
//html
<router-outlet name="manager"></router-outlet>

//routing
loadChildren: 'app/xxxmodule/thisxxx.module#ManagerModule'
```

Comment: I just ran into this today, it looks like it's still an issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12842

Comment: yes, I managed it with some work arounds

Comment: What were your work arounds?

Comment: i left using named outlet nad handling my component loading in [hidden] conditions

Comment: check this answer for workaround or possible solution-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482230/angular-4-lazy-loading-with-named-router-outlet-not-working/47487220#47487220

Answer (score 0):

Before Angular 11 this was a bug in angular and was not possible. For reference find github issue link below :-

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12842

Its fixed in angular 11 and changelog of angular 11 confirms that. please find the link below of changelog and search 12842 in changelog page.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md