# Angular 4 Lazy loading with named router-outlet not working

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have a problem with lazy loading not about to route to a named router-outlet.  Can someone look at where I when wrong?  I have a mainpage where there is a link to Product -> default router outlet and Product Detail -> named router outlet.

```
  <div>
   <div><a [routerLink]="['product']"> Product </a> </div>
   <div><a [routerLink]="['productdetail',{outlets:{productdetail: 'detail'}}]"> Product Detail </a> </div>
  <div> <router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
  <div> <router-outlet name="detail"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Below is the plunker code.

[Plunker Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/W3nhtAvghzwzWkQOj9N6?p=preview)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is known bug, you can track the issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482)

> The workaround or we can say solution to this issue is, use non-empty paths for your top
>   level routes if auxilary(i.e. named) routes exist in a lazy loaded module.

The only flaw I can see is, an additional url segment added in routes

MainRoutingModule: Top level non-empty path(i.e. "path: 'load'")

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MainpageComponent } from './mainpage.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';
import { ProductDetailComponent } from './productdetail.component';

const childroutes: Routes = [

 { path: 'load', component: MainpageComponent  ,
    children: [ 
      {path: 'product', component: ProductComponent
      {path: 'productdetail', component: ProductDetailComponent,
        outlet: 'detail' 
      },

    ]
 },


];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(childroutes);

const newLocal: NgModule = {
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(childroutes) ],
    exports: [RouterModule, ],
    declarations: []
};

@NgModule(newLocal)


export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

MainpageComponent:The correct syntax to use the secondary routes.

> [routerLink]="[{outlets:{detail:['productdetail']}}]"

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  template: `
  <div>

  <div><a [routerLink]="['product']"> Product </a> </div>
  <div><a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{detail:['productdetail']}}]"> Product Detail </a> </div>
  <div> <router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
  <div> <router-outlet name="detail"></router-outlet>

</div>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class MainpageComponent {}
```

LoginComponent:

> Use [routerLink]="['mainpage/load']" to load the main module.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  template: `This is login page place holder <br> <a [routerLink]="['mainpage/load']">Go to Main Page</a>`,

})

export class LoginComponent implements Oninit, OnDestroy {
constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

Demo:https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZpNL3lvbRbexLzQqRZh?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is a bug.  Thanks again for fixing the code.  Hope this will help others.

Comment: The referenced issue is closed. You can track it now here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12842

Comment: I'm trying to get a Nativscript-angular app up and running and this just fixed an issue for me regarding routing. Thank you!

Comment: @mohit-uprim

I have nested lazy loaded modules in my application and am trying to route to a lazy module inside of another component with a named router, how can I change my routing configurations to allow for this?

I have my demo code here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-routeroutlets?embed=1&file=src/app/dashboard/modules/content/components/sidebar/sidebar.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Let's say routes are part of **profile** ProfileComponent (*example.com/profile*)

***profile.component.ts***

```
<a routerLink="/profile/about">About</a>
<a routerLink="/profile/edit">Edit</a>
<a routerLink="/profile/settings">Settings</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

There are three different components:

- AboutComponent
- EditComponent
- SettingsComponent

Then routes will look like:

```
{
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'about',
            component: AboutComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'edit',
            component: EditComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'settings',
            component: SettingsComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if we have 3 different modules instead of components?  I have a login and 3 more routes that are lazy loaded modules with close to 5 submodules in each one, so how does it change the outlet calls since we cannot add outlet parameter to lazy loaded routes and all subfolders are in the same root level which is app folder, so how this has to be implemented?

Comment: my routes are like this:
```
{ path: "", canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: "./login/login.module#LoginModule" },
    { path: "login", loadChildren: "./login/login.module#LoginModule" },
    { path: "home", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },
    { path: "message", loadChildren: "./message/message.module#MessageModule" },
    { path: "newConversation", loadChildren: "./newConversation/newConversation.module#NewConversationModule" },
    { path: "account", loadChildren: "./account/account.module#AccountModule" },
``` 
how do we call the named outlet exactly?

Comment: Hey @LuisParada Please check this answer if it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857876/angular-2-submodule-routing-and-nested-router-outlet

Comment: But this isn't lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

Got the [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/outlet-problem-lazy-cvftqe) to the problem, by avoiding empty paths "".
Thanks to the courtesy of  [Domenic Helfenstein](https://github.com/domenichelfenstein), who took time to reproduce the problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/outlet-problem-lazy).