# Angular 5 Cannot match any routes on named outlet of lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-router, routerlink, router-outlet

My Route of the Root Module is like this:

```
        RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'management-portal', pathMatch: 'full' },            
        { path: 'management-portal', loadChildren: './xxx/management-portal.module#ManagementPortalModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },          
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
    ], {
       enableTracing: true 
    })
```

It works as expected , I can route to ManagementPortalModule after login. Let's take a look of my lazy-loaded ManagementPortalModule.

There is a named router-outlet.

```
 <router-outlet name='sub'></router-outlet>
```

My Route in ManagementPortalModule.

```
    RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '', component: ManagementPortalComponent,        
    children: [            
        { path: '', component: Test1Component, outlet: 'sub' },
        { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component, outlet: 'sub' }            
    ]
  }         
])
```

It can load the Test1Component in the 'sub' outlet at the beginning. I want to route to Test2Component when I click on a link

```
<a  [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sub: ['test2'] } }]"></a>
```

The generated Url

> /management-portal/(sub:test2)

nothing happened when I clicked.Then I tried

```
<a [routerLink]="['',{ outlets: { sub: ['test2'] } }]">
```

Url

> /management-portal(sub:test2)

I think the url is in correct format according to [this](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-4-crisis-center-feature) , Then error occured when I clicked

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test2'

Please Help, many thanks!

Comment: check my recent answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482230/angular-4-lazy-loading-with-named-router-outlet-not-working/47487220#47487220

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try non-empty, top-level path with named outlet routing.

Route in ManagementPortalModule.

```
    RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'load', component: ManagementPortalComponent,        
    children: [            
        { path: '', component: Test1Component, outlet: 'sub' },
        { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component, outlet: 'sub' }            
    ]
  }         
])
```

For more details refer: [Angular 4 Lazy loading with named router-outlet not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482230/angular-4-lazy-loading-with-named-router-outlet-not-working/47487220#47487220)

Comment: You absolute hero!