# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'server/basic

Tags: angular

I get such an error with `outlet: 'xxx'`

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'server/basic
```

Router:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
  {
    path: 'server', component: ManagementComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'basic', component: ManagementDetailsComponent, outlet: 'xxx'}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

ManagementComponent:

```
<div>
    <router-outlet name="xxx"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Without nested outlet seems to work but its not what I want to have.

Comment: How do you get the error? Calling router.navigate or with a routerLink? Can you show your code?

Comment: Think this has been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954703/angular-8-nested-routes-and-multiple-router-outlet-doesnt-work

Comment: @David non of these. Just changing url in browser like: http://localhost:4200/server (it works) http://localhost:4200/server/basic (not working)

Comment: @YoniAffuta got right. Named router-outlet is not needed there